# Clarification about COMMIT and ROLLBACK in IF statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to do this exercise: 
Decrease the price by 10% with the description "Pay TV"  and COMMIT the changes if the sum of the price with the description "Pay TV" and "minibar" are > 100000.

I'd like to know if with my solution, in the case of a false condition, every change will be ROLLBACK. I'm not sure how COMMIT and ROLLBACK works.

This is my solution

```
--SPESE_EXTRA (cod, description, price)

DECLARE 
CURSOR C IS
SELECT *
FROM SPESE_EXTRA;

RECORD_C C%ROWTYPE;

SOMMA INT;

BEGIN 

OPEN C;
LOOP
FETCH C INTO RECORD_C;
EXIT WHEN C%NOTFOUND;
RECORD_C.PRICE := RECORD_C.PRICE *0.9;
UPDATE SPESE_EXTRA
SET ROW = RECORD_C;
WHERE COD = RECORD_C.COD;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C;

SELECT SUM(price) INTO SOMMA
FROM SPESE_EXTRA
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Pay TV' OR DESCRIPTION = 'mini bar';

IF SOMMA > 100000 THEN
COMMIT;
ELSE
ROLLBACK;

end;
```

Comment: Performing a business operation inside a transaction, and then rolling the transaction back if the result exceeds a certain threshold, doesn't sound like a very good idea to me.  The [purpose of transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is to [make a set of operations reliably atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), not to implement business logic rules.

Comment: What did you say it's right, but this is a homework and I must follow this request. I'd like to know if this solution can work with the request of the exercise.

Comment: Well, the way COMMIT and ROLLBACK works is that you execute some operations, and if you COMMIT, all of the work is committed to the database.  If you ROLLBACK, none of the work is committed; the database is left in the state it was before you executed any of the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the whole cursor loop using a single `update` statement. Then you can find the total price with a single `select sum(price)` query and decide whether to commit or roll back based on the result.

This is the literal interpretation of the requirement:

```
declare
    discounted_total spese_extra.price%type;
begin
    savepoint before_discount;

    -- Decrease the price with the description "Pay TV" by 10%
    update spese_extra
    set    price = price * 0.9
    where  description = 'Pay TV';

    select sum(price) into discounted_total
    from   spese_extra
    where  description in ('Pay TV', 'minibar');

    dbms_output.put_line('Total price after discount: ' || discounted_total);

    --  COMMIT the changes if the sum of the price with the description
    -- "Pay TV" and "minibar" are > 100000
    if discounted_total > 100000 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Commit');
        commit;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Rollback');
        rollback to before_discount;
    end if;
end;
```

The `savepoint` lets us roll back to a specific point in the transaction. It's possible that you made other changes right before you called this block, and you didn't want to undo them all.

However, from an efficiency perspective it feels wrong to scan the table twice. We could test the total first with a query and then decide whether or not to go ahead with the update based on the result:

```
declare
    discounted_total spese_extra.price%type;
begin
    select sum(price * case when description = 'Pay TV' then 0.9 else 1 end)
    into   discounted_total
    from   spese_extra
    where  description in ('Pay TV', 'minibar');

    dbms_output.put_line('Total price after discount: ' || discounted_total);

    if discounted_total > 100000 then
        update spese_extra
        set    price = price * 0.9
        where  description = 'Pay TV';

        dbms_output.put_line('Commit');
        commit;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Rollback');
        rollback to before_discount;
    end if;
end;
```

However, there is still a risk that the table might get updated by another session in between you checking the total and applying the update. Instead, you could apply the update, capture the new total using the `returning into` clause, and decide whether to commit or roll back:

```
declare
    discounted_total spese_extra.price%type;
begin
    savepoint before_discount;

    update spese_extra
    set    price = price * case when description = 'Pay TV' then 0.9 else 1 end
    where  description in ('Pay TV', 'minibar')
    returning sum(price) into discounted_total;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total price after discount: ' || discounted_total);

    if discounted_total > 100000 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Commit');
        commit;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Rollback');
        rollback to before_discount;
    end if;
end;
```

Or else, put the condition in the update itself:

```
begin
    update spese_extra
    set    price = price * 0.9
    where  description = 'Pay TV'
    and    exists
           ( select 1
             from   spese_extra
             where  description in ('Pay TV', 'minibar')
             having sum(price * case when description = 'Pay TV' then 0.9 else 1 end) > 100000 );

    if sql%rowcount > 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Commit');
        commit;
    end if;
end;
```

In answer to your question, `COMMIT` commits everything you have changed since the last commit or rollback (or the start of your session, if you haven't committed or rolled back). `ROLLBACK` similarly undoes all your changes since the start of the transaction or an explicitly named savepoint.

Answer (score 1):

- Commit will commit everything since the last commit (or rollback).
- Rollback will rollback everything since the last commit (or rollback) (note that there are *savepoints* you can use, so there's a possibility to rollback to savepoint, but that's not what you have here)

Which means that commit will really commit every update you make. The same goes for rollback.

As of your code, it should be *fixed*. A new variable is to be used (to calculate new price). You can't update the whole "row" (whatever you meant it is) but a column in a table. Something like this:

```
declare 
  cursor c is
    select *
    from spese_extra;
  record_c    c%rowtype;
  new_price   spese_extra.price%type;
  somma       int;
begin 
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into record_c;
    exit when c%notfound;

    new_price := record_c.price * 0.9;

    update spese_extra
      set price = new_price
      where cod = record_c.cod;
  end loop;
  close c;

  select sum(price) 
    into somma
    from spese_extra
    where description = 'Pay TV' 
       or description = 'mini bar';

  if somma > 100000 then
    commit;
  else
    rollback;
  end if;    
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the fix

Comment: *"you can't update the whole row"* - actually [you can](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#LNPLS-GUID-11D63245-591D-4CBF-BFBA-8F3C0AE0E968), although I'm not sure it's necessary here.

Comment: Hmm, look at that! Today I learnt something new. Thank you, @William!